# Clang equivalent no exceptions flag

Tags: c, visual-c++, build, clang

I'm trying to move from msvc to clang and I'm having trouble finding info on some of the flags I'm using. Also, I know there is clang-cl but I'm trying to use zig cc as my compiler and it only excepts normal clang flags as far as I know.

In msvc I use -Eha- since I don't use exceptions and don't want compiler to generate any exception handling code. Is there an equivalent flag on clang? Or is this disabled by default? Also, I'm not linking to the CRT and in order to do this with MSVC I'm disabling security checks with -GS- and stack probing with -Gs9999999 (according to this guide https://hero.handmade.network/forums/code-discussion/t/94-guide_-_how_to_avoid_c_c++_runtime_on_windows). Is there an equivalent with clang? I searched for some keywords in clangs compiler flag documentation but having trouble finding info

Edit:

Was given a suggestion to try to add the option 'clang:-fno_exceptions' to clang-cl but got the warning: "clang-cl: warning: fno-exceptions: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]". Tried adding it as an argument to lld-link but get unknown argument.

Here is the argument list I'm passing with clang-cl

```
REM -GS- tells compiler to not worry about security calls (like __security_cookie) that would typically be inserted with c libs. -Gs99999999999 basically says don't worry about __chkdsk for checking stack overruns
set compiler_flags=-clang:-g -clang:-fdebug-macro -clang:-O0 -clang:-fno-exceptions -GS- -clang:-mstack-probe-size=9999999 -wd4505 -wd4101 -wd4530 -w14700 -wd4100 -we4820 -wd4201 -wd4189 -fno-builtin

REM -STACK:0x100000,0x100000 is setting function stack default to 1MB. Can increase this if we need to. Keep in mind though this also increases default stack size for all threads created
set linker_flags=-subsystem:windows -machine:x64 -incremental:no -opt:ref -debug:full -ignore:4099 -NODEFAULTLIB -STACK:0x100000,0x100000
```

Comment: Are you passing in `-fno_exceptions` or `-fno-exceptions`? Please copy-paste (literally copy-paste) the **full** command line argument you're passing in. Something seems lost in translation. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-fexceptions

Comment: There are no exceptions in C, so there is no need to disable any.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Just wanted to make sure compiler wouldn't add any extra code I didn't need